# Windows 10 - Boot Time

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, bios

I noticed that my Desktop has a long boot time. In the task manager it shows last bios time is 21-23 seconds. However I timed it, I am getting over 30 seconds to moment the Splash screen of my BIOS shows up.

My specs:
 - I7-8700k 3.7 GHz 
 - Asus Maximus X Code Motherboard
 - 32 GB RAM 3600 Vengence DDR4
 - Samsung 970 EVO nvme SSD m.2 (where Windows is installed)
 - 1 TB HDD - Barracuda (backups of where I store my games and large applications)

I was getting the slow boot when I had  windows 10 and an old BIOS version. So I decided to clear the CMOS of my MOBO which will restore BIOS and format my SSD with a clean install of windows 10.

I did a clean install of windows 10 pro on my SSD.

On disk partition, I see my HDD which is a storage device being primary. Is that causing an issue?

I just want to understand here, why after a clean install the PC is taking time. My idea of taking time is based on my friends with the same PC (actually having 16 GB ram) are running at 7-9 seconds?

Comment: Do you have hybrid shutdown enabled or disabled?  Your boot times should be at least 1/3 of your current boot times.  I have a similar Samsung NVME drive and my boot times are less then 10 seconds, total boot time, with all programs running.  However, if the startup applications are installed on a HDD, that might explain the slow boot times.  Configure your system for a minimal boot configuration (no unnecessary applications) and compare the results to your typical boot times;  Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question.

Comment: How long does the BIOS + Mainboard components initialization takes? Those Mainboards with dozens of extra chips require quite some time to initialize (e.g. RAID adapters). Therefore I only buy Mainboards with just the necessary components - saves money, power and boot time. If you don't use all components of your system disable them in BIOS. And make sure you install Windows in UEFI mode.

Comment: I promise @ramhound that I’ll edit my post soon when I collect more data. Mind telling me what hybrid shutdown is? The HDD is only used to backup old games and pictures. No application running. If I check on disk partition it shows as it’s a primary NTFS storage. Although, I actually tried to disabled it in BIOS, see if it will make any difference to my boot time and it did not.

Comment: @Mikeez - You should do the proper research into what Hybrid Shutdown is with respect to Windows

Answer (score 0):

I quote from
[What Is “Last BIOS Time” in the Windows Task Manager](https://www.howtogeek.com/265623/what-is-last-bios-time-in-the-windows-task-manager/):

> The “Last BIOS time” figure is the amount of time it took for your computer’s **BIOS** (or, more accurately, your computer’s UEFI firmware) to **initialize your hardware** before it begins booting Windows when you start your computer.

This is likely a problem with your BIOS firmware, although it can also be a problem
with one of your devices. It is not connected to Windows.

Check if your BIOS version is the recent
[Version 2301](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-MAXIMUS-X-CODE/HelpDesk_BIOS/)
from 2020/04/28. If not, update to the latest (very carefully).

Comment: Yep, looks like your hardware has a hard time passing POST (Power-On Self-Test). Your newly flashed BIOS could be the culprit, or one or several of your components are late in raising their hand during roll-call.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have searched A LOT before posting. I understand what the BIOS time is. That is why I am confused, shouldn't my SSD be ready within seconds...? How do I troubleshoot which device? I am on the latest BIOS Version. @Didier Is there a way to see which hardware is having hard time passing POST? before flashing the BIOS it was also running around the same speed (1 second slower)

Comment: This happens at firmware level, so it's hard to tell, but it might come from a different order of initialization, from one BIOS to the next, or different timeout values being enforced by the BIOS before declaring everyone as good for the service, or redundant tests being performed during POST... A more recent version of your BIOS also means that security measures that maybe weren't performed with the old one are now enforced. You can check the state of your CSM (Compatibility Support Module) if you're in UEFI-compliant mode, or if Legacy isn't enabled first, CSM second. And your SATA status.

Comment: Verify in your boot sequence if the SSD is set as first. See if the BIOS does memory check on boot. Disable in the BIOS devices you don't use. Otherwise, try [these instructions](https://mediawiki.middlebury.edu/LIS/Computer_is_slow_during_BIOS_startup) and let us know.

Comment: harrymc @Didier I have done my research a little and according to the configuration I do have my SSD running at the first and actually everything else is disabled. I have fast boot enabled for both normal start and after AC loss. 

I am running UEFI Only, legacy disabled. I will try the instruction you sent. Although, quickly looking over it, I already done all that :)!

Comment: If all else fails and there is no explanation, perhaps you should return the old BIOS version that worked well.